# Easiest way to split up a large controller file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails controller file that is too large (~900 lines - api_controller). I'd like to just split it up like something like this:

```
api_controller.rb
api_controller_item_admin.rb
api_controller_web.rb
```

I don't want to split into multiple controllers. What would be the preferred way to do this? Could I just require the new parts at the end? like:

```
require './api_controller_item_admin'
require './api_controller_web'
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like it should be a bunch of different controllers in a namespace. Why are you so opposed to having multiple controllers?

Comment: thx for input but a refactoring is fundamentally different from what I'm asking about

Comment: Except from the sound of it a refactoring is exactly what you need, and you're just looking for a way to put it off.

Comment: honestly, not my code base (and I bill by the hour); length of a file is hardly a reason for refactoring. I have more interesting things to work on. Seems like ruby isn't able to handle this.

Comment: It's not just that its a large file, it's that it's a large file that you've seemingly stuffed your entire API into. Unless the controller only ever deals with one model object, it belongs in separate controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always refactor the functionality you believe doesn't belong to one controller only, to separate file(s) somewhere in your `lib` directory. You can then make those files auto-required and you will have all their functionality at your disposal anywhere in the app. Here's how:

```
# in [config/application.rb]
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

My advice: instead of thinking of splitting a huge controller into smaller chunks, do torture your brain and force it to think about this problem as extracting a functionality that doesn't quite belong in your controller, to other files.

Comment: thx for suggestion but I really want to manually include this file inline and not do autoincluding. thx

Comment: I have read that there are a number of ways of doing this in Ruby. But to be fair with you, I never pursued them. And since I cannot imagine how would your scenario absolutely positively forbid auto-loading, I won't propose anything more here. On a side note, I never noticed a significant slowdown in my Rails projects after including auto-loading sources.

Comment: thx for response. the main reason I want to do it manually is so that other developers can see that we're doing a one-time split of this file. The second we start doing auto-loading, I'm going to come back and see that our code base has 10 or 20 autoloaded things. Just my experience.

Comment: You can always put code comment on the top of your controller, explicitly conveying its dependencies.